# Anime about a kid and his friend(s) who had access to hi-tech cars that were unlocked with special keys

Tags: story-identification, anime

My daughter stumbled on a show; I want to say it was on Netflix, but maybe it was Hulu.

The anime centered around a kid and his friend(s) who had access to hi-tech cars. I want to say one of the kids dad/grandpa/uncle built them in his garage.

It was circa 2020. She started watching *[Tobot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobot)* and it’s kind of like that, but these are full-sized cars that were unlocked with special keys, I think. The antagonists kidnapped the person who built them and the main kid was trying to find out what happened.

Comment: Hi, you should post that as an answer to your own question instead of editing it into the question!

Answer (score 2):

According to an edit the OP made to their question, this is ***[Tobot V](https://tobot.fandom.com/wiki/Tobot_V_(cartoon))*** AKA *[Tobot Galaxy Detectives](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12892186/)* (2018-2021).

> A long time ago, there were six Galaxy Weapons from the planet Unicorn that could rule the universe. The cosmic villain, Pulsar, is trying to rule the universe with the 6 Galaxy Weapons. One day, the space ship carrying the galaxy weapons is chased by his minion and found a place to escape. The space ship decided to drop the Galaxy Weapons on Earth, where Tyler, an ace junior detective, discovers Galaxy Weapon 1 and brings his toys to life as Tobots. With their help, they prevent the Pac-Man Gang from taking over Nav City using Galaxy Weapon 2. Eventually, they team up with Princess Zora to keep Star Ring from causing mass destruction.

It's apparently a reboot of the *Tobot* franchise, the [original series](https://tobot.fandom.com/wiki/Tobot_(cartoon)) of which aired from 2010-2015.